# How to use ORDER BY in Power BI DAX?

Tags: powerbi, concatenation, dax, textjoin

I have a DAX which concatenates values from one column in my data.

I want to rank my data by 2 columns right inside my DAX as its concatenating rows randomly.

How can I achieve that?

---

My data looks like -

[image]

---

Now, the problem is that I've sorted by id... But I want to sort by "id" and "name" so that it concatenates data in the same manner.

Currently, it's concatenating for one id as a/b/c and for another id as b/a/c

---

My DAX looks like this -

```
=
VAR ThisID = 'Table'[id]
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX(
        FILTER(
            'Table',
            'Table'[id] = ThisID
        ),
        'Table'[likes],
        "/"
    )
```

---

I tried using 'ORDER BY' with the EVALUATE. But, that's giving ERROR.

Comment: Which columns should be used for the ordering? Can you post a very small example dataset with expected results?

Comment: Hey, I've added an example. Please have a look. :)

Comment: Thanks, but not sure I understand. The formula you posted is concatenating entries from the *likes* column, but in your example it appears to be concatenating entries from the *name* column?

Comment: Yes! I wrote that way (a/b/c) so that it could be easier for you to understand.

Comment: Actually, the values that I want to concatenate are the "likes" column. But, I want to concatenate in the order of "name" column. Like a/b/c... instead of b/c/a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the *name* column as one of `CONCATENATEX`'s *orderBy_expression* parameters:

```
=
VAR ThisID = 'Table'[id]
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX(
        FILTER(
            'Table',
            'Table'[id] = ThisID
        ),
        'Table'[likes],
        "/",
        'Table'[name]
    )
```